# Change "remove icon" functionality in ArrayInput field in react admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to write my own function for remove icon. by default when clicking on the icon, the
TextInput will be gone. I want to do some extra things when clicking that icon. here is my code:

```
<ArrayInput source="items">
   <SimpleFormIterator >
    <FormDataConsumer>
     {({ scopedFormData = {}, getSource, ...rest }) => {
      <TextInput source="name"} />}                
     </FormDataConsumer>
   </SimpleFormIterator>
  </ArrayInput>
```

[the mark icon in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD5V6.jpg)